# Is it possible to change the transactional e-mail process in Magento CE 1.8.1

Tags: email, magento, paypal, magento-1.8, transactional-email

I am looking to change the transactional e-mail ordering for my Magento 1.8.1 install.

I've found a lot of ways to automate this but none to do it manually.

Ideally I want to have this order of e-mails:

Order placed - Order Information email & separate payment confirmation e-mail
Order Manually shipped - shipping e-mail
Order Manually Invoiced -  Invoice e-mail

Currently I have PayPal set to sale and the e-mail orders go like this:

Order placed - order information e-mail and automatically invoiced
Order shipped - shipping email

I know that I can change to authorize and capture but then this still sends the invoice before the shipping.

Thanks in advance for any advice :)